# How can I activate code folding in spyder 4.0.1 when there is no checkbox in preferences/editor to do so?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, spyder, windows-subsystem-for-linux, code-folding

I use WSL on my windows laptop and am perfectly fine to use spyder via VcXsrv. Current version: 4.0.1 - if I try to update to a newer version it tells me that 'all requested packages are already installed'. Additionally, I updated anaconda as suggested. I use python 3.7.9

However, there is neither code folding happening in the editor, nor can I activate it via tools-> preferences-> editor, tab 'display' where it is supposed to be. Searching for an answer, I found that other people also seem to be missing this option.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Code folding doesn't require any special option to be activated. However, there were several problems related to that that are already fixed in our latest version in Anaconda (4.1.5). So you need to update to it, which you can do by creating a new conda environment and installing Spyder on it.